# VSTO: MS Project - Adding a project as a subproject causes all tasks in Sub Project to get new GUID

Tags: vsto, ms-project

When I add an existing project as a subproject to another project, all the GUIDs in the subproject get recalculated!

Opening the original subproject file (say F1) separately continues to show the old GUID, but the new project (which has file F1 as a subproject) shows new GUIDs for the subproject.

Is there a way of preventing the recalculation of these GUIDs?

Answer (score 0):

There are to ways to add a Subproject to existing project: Link and Insert

- Link preserve original Guids and you can even link a project as readonly into your master. Any changes done in the sub project will affect the original project. Of course if the link isn't readonly.
- Insert just copy data from the original project to the destination project. As the result all Guids are new just because all the tasks are new. But in the case any change in the copied project will not affect the original project.

Comment: I am "linking" the project - at least I think I am. I go to the Project tab in the Ribbon and click on "Insert Subproject". I then select the project file (in the File Select dialog), the "Link to project" check box is checked.

I still see new GUIDs. Am I linking incorrectly?

Comment: When you link a project - MSP keeps separate task IDs for the linked project. So you see in your project in the 1st column: 1, 2, 3, <here linked project starts>: 1, 2, 3

Comment: I am not sure I followed you there. To clarify a bit more, when I open the subproject file separately I see different GUIDs as compared to when I include that subproject into another project (linked).

Comment: I checked several of my linked projects: GUID column has the same values does not matter how project is open: from master or directly. Probably you should claim a ticket to Microsoft.